# Updating nested useState seems to modify the original data

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I have an implementation of a Text Field input alongside a table in which I'm trying to update the state of staged Data before I submit the data to an API.

In the Dialogs parent component, I have the data defined which I want to show in a table as the original state.

The current problem I'm having is the inputted data is somehow updating the original data's state even though I'm not directly touching this data.

Below is a reproduction of it on Codesandbox, So when you open the link typing into the edit value field **should not** update the current stock field and I don't see why it is.

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/textinputproblem-p2fvh)

Here is the callback that modifies the state:

```js
const handleUpdateDip = (value, tank) => {
  const newData = stagedData;
  const foundIndex = newData.dips.findIndex((d) => d.tank === tank);

  if (foundIndex !== -1) {
    newData.dips[foundIndex].currentStockValue = Number(value);

    setStage({
      ...stagedData,
      dips: newData.dips
    });
  }
};
```

So yeah this one seems weird to me and I've been banging my head against the keyboard trying to understand whats going on with it since last night so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating the current object. Try this

```js
setStage((stage) => {
  const foundIndex = stage.dips.findIndex((d) => d.tank === tank);
  return {
    ...stage,
    dips: stage.dips.map((d, index) => {
      if (foundIndex === index) {
        return { ...d, currentStockValue: Number(value) };
      }
      return d;
    })
  };
});
```

Instead of this

```js
const foundIndex = stagedData.dips.findIndex((d) => d.tank === tank);

if (foundIndex !== -1) {
  stagedData.dips[foundIndex].currentStockValue = Number(value);

  setStage({
    ...stagedData,
    dips: stagedData.dips
  });
}
```

[image: Edit 64136950/updating-nested-usestate-seems-to-modify-the-original-data/64137147#64137147]

Comment: Ok all of you guys are completely correct, yeah at some stage my brain turned off last night while looking at this, thanks for the help, could I ask how does it update data as well when its only used to set the initial state of stagedData?

Comment: You actually did update the array item from `props.data` because it has the same reference with the `stagedData.dip`. My solution works because I recreated the array item from scratch using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which constructs a new array and get rid of the shared reference. @EannaGlavin

Comment: This solution works, but I don't think that's way you should go. If you don't want to modify the value of your ```data``` prop, don't pass it in as a reference to ```useState()``` like you're currently doing. It's easier to simply pass in a copy since you only want the default values and structure of the object anyway. See my answer for more info on that - it works, too, is shorter/less complicated and, in my opinion, cleaner. @EannaGlavin

Comment: @DangerousDetlef I never touch `props.data` in my code. And secondly I don't want to serialize and deserialize the data whenever my component re-renders. My solution is the standard way to update the state by reconstructing the state completely when requested. You solution reconstructs the data at every renders. So no I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it's shouldn't update while the code tells it to do so! This line inside `handleUpdateDip()`:

`stagedData.dips[foundIndex].currentStockValue = Number(value);`

1. You shouldn't directly mutate the state. You should make a copy of it first change whatever you want and then set the state to the new value e.g.:

```
  const handleUpdateDip = (value, tank) => {
    const foundIndex = stagedData.dips.findIndex((d) => d.tank === tank);
    if (foundIndex !== -1) {
      const newStagedData = { ...stagedData };
      newStagedData.dips[foundIndex].currentStockValue = Number(value);
      setStage(newStagedData);
    }
  };
```

2. `stagedData.dips[foundIndex].currentStockValue = Number(value);` this line updates the value of `currentStockValue` which is used in the "Current Stock" column.

Comment: yeah, correct I was trying to make a copy of the stagedData array in the handleUpdateDip function last night but couldn't get it to work properly must have removed the line and forgot about it. Anyway, NearHuscarl has exactly what I needed so thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the table cell left of the input field simply uses the same state that is changed in `handleUpdateDip`

```
<TableCell align="right" padding="none">
           {row.currentStockValue}
</TableCell>

<TableCell align="right" padding="none">
      <InputTextField
          id="new-dip"
          type="number"
          inputProps={{
          min: 0,
          style: { textAlign: "right" }
          }}
          defaultValue={row.currentStockValue}
          onChange={(event) =>
          handleUpdateDip(event.target.value, row.tank)
           }
      />
```

both are `currentStockValue`, which `handleUpdateDips` changes in this line

`stagedData.dips[foundIndex].currentStockValue = Number(value);`

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you're thinking. You think that on the one hand, you're updating your state in `handleUpdateDip(event.target.value, row.tank)` with `setStage({...})`, so you're only changing your state `stagedData`.

You value for the "Current Stock", however, is mapped to your `data` variable and not to `stagedData`.

So in the end your question is: Why ist `data` changing when you're only manipulating `stagedData`.

Of course it happens here: `const [stagedData, setStage] = useState(() => data);`
(btw you don't need to use a function here, `const [stagedData, setStage] = useState(data);` is fine). You pass in data by reference here, when your `setState` hits, the reference will be updated and so will your `data`.
(another BTW: don't call your state variable settings functions simply `setState`, this is something used by class components in React. Call them like the state you want to set, e.g. `setStagedData`).

Now, you can elimate this reference, since you only want the initial values anyways. You could do this by passing a copy, like this: `const [stagedData, setStagedData] = useState({...data});` But this still won't work - I not really sure why because I don't know enough about the inner workings of `useState`, but the reason probably is because it's only a shallow copy instead of a deep copy (you can read more about this [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/copying-objects-in-javascript)).

But if we do a deep copy and pass this in, it works and your original `data` will stay untouched. You can deep copy by basically stringifying and then parsing it again (which will not copy any methods the object has, just as a warning).

```js
const copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
const [stagedData, setStagedData] = useState(copy);
```

And just like that your current stock will stay the same:
[image]

I forked your [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/textinputproblem-forked-4s2vo?file=/src/App.js), so you can see it for yourself.

Comment: Ok yeah fair play that makes sense, I've a bit to learn on how js inner working actually works alright! thanks for the write-up and your time!